# Find an explicit formula (as explicit as possible) for $a_k$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

Let $a_k$ be defined as follows: $$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^na_k(x)_k$$ where $(x)_k = x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-k+1)$. Find a formula that describes $a_k$ as explicitly as possible, in terms of a famous number family (Stirling numbers in this case).
I approached it the following way:

$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}x^k$$ and $$\sum_{k=0}^na_k(x)_k=\sum_{k=0}^na_k\sum_{i=0}^ks(k,i)x^i$$

Here, $s(k,i)$ denotes the Stirling numbers of the first kind, as $(x)_k=\sum_{i=0}^ks(k,i)x^i$. Writing out some terms by hand, and rearranging, I found the following:

$$\sum_{k=0}^na_k\sum_{i=0}^ks(k,i)x^i = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k\bigg[\sum_{i=k}^na_is(i,k)\bigg]$$
which, with the first (original) equality, gives us: $${n\choose k} =\sum_{i=k}^ka_is(i,k)$$ as these are the respective coefficients of $x^k$ in the defined sum.

This is as far as I got, and I'm not even sure if it's correct. Does anyone know how to go from here, or is this regarded as 'explicit enough'?

Comment: I take issue with the very first statement of the question (i.e. the definition of the sequence $a$). It's very bad manners to not define something in the form of "$\text{something }=\text{ something else}$". In the question the definition is given implicitly, but who knows if this is even possible? In calculus there's a big theorem to define functions implicitly, it even has its own name. Why would people make due without something similar here?

Comment: What is the definition of $(x)_0$?

Comment: @GitGud : $\{(x)_k\}_{0\le k\le n}$ is a basis for ${\mathbb R)_n[X]$, where is the problem ?

Comment: @AndréPorto : by definition, an empty product is equal to $1$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS The problem is saying something similar to "Given functions $g$ and $h$, where $h$ isn't invertible, let $f$ be given by $g=h\circ f$".

Comment: @GitGud well I can't change the problem I was given, but I can see where you're coming from. Also with the analogy of function compositions I can understand that there might be a fundamental problem. I also couldn't really find an explicit form of $s(n,k)$ online (some forms get really messy), so maybe it's in its nature for this equation not to have a real explicit form. But, given the problem, would you consider my answer as explicit enough?

Comment: I understand that the problem was given to you like this, I got that right. As for the rest... Who knows? This is subjective from the get go. Sorry, I can't help.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer you are right! I corrected the typo. Also, thank you for your more explicit answer.

Comment: @Marc: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not specify which kind of Stirling numbers is to use. Here is a variant based upon ${n\brace k}$, the *[Stirling numbers of the Second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)*. We use  $x^{\underline{k}}=x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)$ to denote the falling factorials.

The *Stirling numbers of the second kind* ${n\brace k}$ are given for non-negative integers $n$ as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\brace k}x^{\underline{k}}=x^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (1) for integral $n\geq 0$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{n+1\brace k}x^{\underline{k}}&=x^{n+1}\tag{2}\\
> \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}{n+1\brace k}(x-1)^{\underline{k-1}}&=x^{n}\tag{3}\\
> \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n+1\brace k+1}(x-1)^{\underline{k}}&=x^{n}\tag{4}\\
> \sum_{k=0}^n\color{blue}{{n+1\brace k+1}}x^{\underline{k}}&=(1+x)^n\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>   and we conclude $\color{blue}{a_k={n+1\brace k+1}}$.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use (1) and set $n\to n+1$.
- In (3) we use $x^{\underline{k}}=x\cdot (x-1)^{\underline{k-1}}$ with $k>0$ and divide the identity by $x$. We set the lower limit of the sum to $1$, since ${n+1\brace 0}=0$ for $n>0$.
- In (4) we shift the index $k$ by one to start from $0$.
- In (5) we shift $x$ by one $x\to x+1$.